# how to remove class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

how to remove class using jQuery?

```
<div class="class_name">
This is Test
</div>
```

Comment: -1 In all fairness, try looking at http://api.jquery.com, there is great documentation on there and you would have found this very easily.

Comment: This could have been answered by looking at the jQuery API docs, which are really well-written and full of good examples.

Comment: you could find this yourself by typing in your question at google or the jquery site. Stackoverflow is easy to get answers but please do some research yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".class_name").removeClass("class_name");

})
```

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

```
$('p').removeClass('yourClass');
```